# Simple harmonic motion~

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

I am stuck in a question which says that:
A particle moves on the X- axis according to equation $x=A+Bsin(\omega t)$. The motion is simple harmonic. Find the amplitude of SHM.

The answer of the above problem is   "*B*".
My question is: how the above equation is simple harmonic? I do not know how to reach the answer.
If there were two trig functions in  the question then it would be easy to solve for the answer using vector addition method! The "*A*" in the equation is troubling me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constant $A$ is simply a vertical shift by $A$ units (this shift can be up--if $A>0$--or down if $A<0$).

By the way, the amplitude is $|B|$

Comment: Thank you for giving me an explanation. Now I understand the error that I was doing!

Answer (score 0):

Write

$$x(t)=A+B\cos\left(\frac\pi2-\omega t\right)$$

and then we easily see the [amplitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion) indeed is $\;B\;$  . The $\;A\;$ is just translation.

Comment: You mean that A has nothing to do with harmonic motion. How?

Comment: Okay now I realize what you wanted to say

Comment: Okay now I realize what you wanted to say. The A is just a translation. and in SHM the position function is taken in the frame where origin lies at the mean position of SHM. The above function is written in the frame where origin does not lie at the mean position. Thank you very much Timbuc!!!!!